# R find all paths from all children to all parents

Tags: r, parent-child, igraph

Working in energy systems, I'm trying to identify all routes from the parents to the children, represented in the graph below using R.
I already found the pretty useful library `igraph`, but am not able to achieve my target.
I'm a newbie to graph theory, therefore please be generous with me when using the wrong terminology.

I'm seeking results such as
`1 -> 2 -> 3`
`1 -> 2 -> 4`
`5 -> 4`
`4 -> 6 -> 4`

Where I can identify the parents: `1,5,4` and the "last children" `3,4`

```
library(igraph)
df <- data.frame(c(1,2,2,5,6,4),c(2,3,4,4,4,6))
df_graph <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
plot(df_graph)
```

[image: Graph from chunk above]

Comment: Assuming we are on about the same level re 'graph theory', you might want to look at Bioconductor RBGL, maximum flow, which, for whatever reason I was reading about yesterday and seemed to speak toward what you are trying to achieve. Find a newish ref to it where BiocManager is used and RTM.

Comment: @Chris igraph supports maximum flow, edge connectivity, etc. calculations if that's what the OP wants.

Comment: How to identify the relationship between vertice 4 and 6? Who is the parent or the child?

Comment: Indeed, this is a directed graph with circularity. Therefore, the graph theory and the use of the igraph package is limited. For simplicity purposes, it is possible to consider only one flow from `6 -> 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `all_simple_paths` to find all paths from a vertex to a set of other vertices. For example, the following finds all paths from 1 to 3 or 4.

```
> all_simple_paths(df_graph, "1", c("3", "4"))
[[1]]
+ 3/6 vertices, named, from 11c31e4:
[1] 1 2 4

[[2]]
+ 3/6 vertices, named, from 11c31e4:
[1] 1 2 3
```

Note that since the graph was created from a dataframe, the vertices have string names that do not coincide with their index:

```
> V(df_graph)$name
[1] "1" "2" "5" "6" "4" "3"
```

This is why it was necessary to quote vertex names. If we were to pass in `3` instead of `"3"`, it would be interpreted as the 3rd vertex, which is vertex `"5"`. To avoid this inconvenience, you could use `graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(df))`, which interprets the input as vertex IDs instead of vertex names.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
But is there a possibility
1. identify the parents `1,5,4`
2. identify the ends `3,4`
3. and generate a function that gives me all of those paths

`1 -> 2 -> 3`
`1 -> 2 -> 4`
`5 -> 4`
`4 -> 6 -> 4`

Comment: @JonasSchnidrig I don't understand what you mean by "parents" and "ends". You did not explain this in the question. I got the impression that you already have a list of starting and ending points and just want to find paths between them.

Comment: When having a look at the graph, one can identify the nodes from where everything starts `1,5` ("parents"), and those where everything ends `3,4` ("ends")

Comment: I don't think we can proceed with this unless you can formulate a precise mathematical definition of "parents" and "ends" instead of just saying that it can be seen by looking at the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of talking about `fathers`, `children` and `ends`, use

- sources, vertices without incoming edges.
- sinks, vertices without outgoing edges.
- and detect and remove loops manually.

Try this.

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph(c(1,2, 2,3, 2,4, 5,4, 6,4), directed=TRUE)
stopifnot(length(feedback_arc_set(g)) == 0)
sinks   <- V(g)[degree(g, mode = 'out')==0]
sources <- V(g)[degree(g, mode = 'in') ==0]
res <- c()
for (i in seq_along(sources) ){
  res <- append(res, all_simple_paths(g, sources[i], sinks, mode="out"))
}
res
```